How does oxygen binding alter the electron configuration and magnetic properties of hemoglobin?
Could someone please tell me:
What is the electron configuration of the iron ion in deoxyhemoglobin, and how does this configuration contribute to its paramagnetic nature? And vice versa for oxyhemoglobin.
Unfortunately I only find very rudimentary explanations of this in the articles describing the BOLD method. Therefore, I would really really really appreciate any insights into the underlying quantum mechanical principles that govern these changes. Thankssssss

This is easy to google, and using your exact phrasing, the first hit (after your question here or on Physics.se) was a PNAS article explaining it well enough. As we require evidence of prior research here, I recommending repeating your search, and if there's a particular quote that confuses you, edit the quote and a link to address a specific issue. Thanks.

In addition to what @anongoodnurse said above, please be aware the cross-posting is heavily frowned upon on SE. Since your question on Physics has been closed, I'll let this remain, but you need to address the prior research issue or it may be closed for that reason.
